# How to store a number longer than 10 digits in Java

Tags: java, mysql, numberformatexception

I have a problem with my code

```
nama=txtNama.getText().trim();
int nim =Integer.parseInt(txtNIM.getText());
alamat=txtAlamat.getText().trim();
int telp =Integer.parseInt(txtTelp.getText());
```

In the code Integer

```
int nim =Integer.parseInt(txtNIM.getText());
int telp =Integer.parseInt(txtTelp.getText());
```

I only can input 10 number, if I have input more than 10 number it will be an error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1111111111111"

Thanks for your attention and help.

Comment: you probably should use a bigger size data type for both java and sql.

Comment: `"It's about Netbeans and MySQL"` --- it has nothing whatsoever to do with NetBeans and little to do with NetBeans. It's about *Java*.

Comment: Do you mean you want to input `long`er intergers? ;)

Comment: Is there anybody in here can help me to make 'Multi Client Server' with Database and GUI with my code?

Comment: `"Is there anybody in here can help me to make 'Multi Client Server' with Database and GUI with my code?"` -- Seriously? You've posted 6 lines of code, and there's no way that anyone can help you  with what you requested based on this post or any post actually, since that request is way too broad. You will want to learn and do first things first and by baby steps, one at a time, you will be able to create your program.

Answer (score 7):

An `Integer` in java is 32 bits long, it can only hold values from [`-2147483648`, `2147483647`].

Use a `long`

```
long nim = Long.parseLong(txtNIM.getText());
long telp = Long.parseLong(txtTelp.getText());
```

A `long` is 64 bits, it can hold values from [`-9223372036854775808`, `9223372036854775807`]

If you must go bigger, you can use `BigInteger` class.

Comment: Whoever down-voted should explain why. I think this is the best answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's solved, but still have an error

Comment: Aug 27, 2015 10:06:50 PM titrixsinputtable.FInput btnSimpanActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'nim' at row 1

Comment: Candra, MySQL has the same size for integers, 32 bits. You must change the data type in your MySQL table from INT to BIGINT